# Can't edit /etc/modules and add "bcm2708_wdog"

Tags: terminal, watchdog

i tried following the directions here for the watchdog
Link: *http://pi.gadgetoid.co.uk/post/001-who-watches-the-watcher*

i can't get even past the first attempt, here's an SS: http://prntscr.com/ohvq1 , i tried adding the line bcm2708_wdog but wrong characters come out or when i press some keys different ones appear like here's an SS: http://prntscr.com/ohvvj , is this normal? i don't really know what to do, still a noob linux user here.. hope someone will help thanks again. please comment first if the question isn't enough.

Comment: It would appear you don't know how to use vi. It might be easier to try with, e.g., `nano` instead until you have the time to learn.

Comment: 10 second `vi` primer... First, use `vim`. Second, type `i` before trying to insert anything. Third, type `ESC` to get back to control mode. Fourth, type `:x` to save and exit. Fifth, Google it.

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need editor to add just 1 line to a file. Use echo. sudo echo "bcm2708_wdog" >> /etc/modules should work.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have issues with `vi` or `vim`.
Either you learn how to use `vi`/`vim`, or you use a less advanced and much simpler editor like `nano`.

If you want to edit `/etc/modules` then you'll have to do it as a superuser, ie

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```